# getting object.geolocation even after GPS is Disabled

Tags: javascript, cordova, google-maps-api-3, geolocation, phonegap-plugins

i am checking whether gps is enabled or not by giving condition like

```
 if (navigator.geolocation) {

    alert("Value "+navigator.geolocation);
    //do something       
}else
{
   alert("Please Enable GPS."); 
}
```

in alert I am getting object.geolocation so given if GPS is off, as I am getting some object it not showing alert.Can anybody help me regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

`navigator.geolocation` is never null if the plugin loads correctly. So you will never print `alert("Please Enable GPS.");` unless the plugin fails to load entirely. The plugin can still load successfully even if you have the GPS turned off.

The correct approach would be to use something like:

```
function success(error) {
    // Handle the error
    // Print alert here is you want
}
function fail(position) {
    // Do something
}

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, fail);
```

More info [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova/geolocation/geolocation.html)